# Find unique collection of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, search

I have a list of cards that contains pokemon cards in "sets". The data is retrieved as JSON (formatting/querying is out of my control).

```
let myList = `
  [{'hand': '1', 'cards': {'charmander','pikachu','squirtle'}},
   {'hand': '2', 'cards': {'charmander','gyarados','jigglypuff'}},
   {'hand': '3', 'cards': {'balbasaur','blastoise','mankey'}}]
  `;
```

I'm not sure what I can utilize to find a unique hand in that list, ie *hand 3* would be the unique one as it does not contain any other card from the other hands.

I created a map and used turning each *hand* into a string to be used as the key and then checked to see if the key already exists. But with the data above, I am not sure how I can ensure that *hand 3* is the truly unique hand as no other cards exist in the other ones.

```
cards = JSON.parse(myList);
let cardMap = new Map();
cards.map((hands) => {
   let handAsStr = hands.cards.toString();
   let matchingValue = cardMap.has(handAsStr);
   if (matchingValue) {
      console.log("Entry exists - Not adding " + handAsStr );
   } 
   else {
      console.log("Adding: " + handAsStr )
      cardMap.set(handAsStr , {hand: hands.hand});
   }
});
```

I thought about converting the names to hex values and then searching to see if that hex value exists anywhere else, but that seems daunting and inefficient.

Any pointers?

Comment: Converting the `myList` to an array is a big task in itself. You are using single quotes and cards have `{}` wrappers instead of `[]`. `JSON.parse()` won't work

Comment: You are using an object for your cards which is invalid, did you want to use an array instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an array for `cards`, you could count all cards of all sets and filter the array by checking the cards, if all cards have a count of one.

```js
function findUnique(array) {
    var count = new Map;
    array.forEach(({ cards }) => cards.forEach(c => count.set(c, (count.get(c) || 0) + 1)));
    return array.filter(({ cards }) => cards.every(c => count.get(c) === 1));
}

var array = [{ hand: '1', cards: ['charmander', 'pikachu', 'squirtle'] }, { hand: '2', cards: ['charmander', 'gyarados', 'jigglypuff'] }, { hand: '3', cards: ['balbasaur', 'blastoise', 'mankey'] }];

console.log(findUnique(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not valid JSON, I suggest to change `cards` to an array, and replace the `'` by `"`.

Once parsed with `JSON.parse()`, you can build a map using `reduce()` to get the number of appearances of each card. You can then use that map to filter your list and keep only the items whose cards appear only once.

```js
const myList = `[
 {'hand': '1', 'cards': ['charmander','pikachu','squirtle']},
 {'hand': '2', 'cards': ['charmander','gyarados','jigglypuff']},
 {'hand': '3', 'cards': ['balbasaur','blastoise','mankey']}
]`;

const list = JSON.parse(myList.replace(/'/g, '"'));

const allCards = list.reduce((acc, { cards }) => {
  cards.forEach(x => acc[x] = acc[x] ? acc[x] + 1 : 1);
  return acc;
}, {});

const uniqueItems = list.filter(({ cards }) => cards.every(x => allCards[x] === 1));

console.log(uniqueItems)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the invalid JSON. I didn't write it properly here from the code I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

Add all items in the array to a `Set` (`uniqueSet`). Iterate the cards with nested `Array.forEach()`. If a `card` is found in the `Map` (`objByCardMap`) remove the current object, and the object stored with the card in the Map from the `Set`. Spread the `Set` and return the array of unique items:

```js
const findUniqueHand = array => {
  const uniqueSet = new Set(array);
  const objByCardMap = new Map();
  
  // iterate the array and then the cards
  array.forEach(o => o.cards.forEach(c => {
    if(objByCardMap.has(c)) { // if a card is found in the Map
      uniqueSet.delete(objByCardMap.get(c)); // remove the object in the map
      uniqueSet.delete(o); // remove the current object
    }
    else objByCardMap.set(c, o); // add the card and it's object ot the map
  }));

  return [...uniqueSet];
}

const array = [{ hand: '1', cards: ['charmander', 'pikachu', 'squirtle'] }, { hand: '2', cards: ['charmander', 'gyarados', 'jigglypuff'] }, { hand: '3', cards: ['balbasaur', 'blastoise', 'mankey'] }];

const result = findUniqueHand(array);

console.log(result);
```